# Create a search bar that uses cmd / ctrl + F to search an iframe

Tags: search

Is it possible to make a search bar that searches like command/control + f to search through an iframe?
We have tried various methods, but have yet to find a solution to search through an iframe (cross-domain .

Comment: Are you assuming that you want the search bar to sit in the parent page, and that you don’t have code access to the IFRAME’s domain?

Comment: Yes, we have access to the IFRAME's domain, but we are unsure on how to add a search bar into our webpage and get it to function properly with the IFRAME, allowing us to filter through the information in the IFRAME.

Comment: In that case, the answer is "yes it's possible". Please create a CodePen / JSFiddle or similar if you'd like further assistance.

Comment: Do you by chance have any clue on how we might be able to add the search bar?

Comment: Yes, but it's not trivial so please do the groundwork and share some meaningful code - at least set up a page with an IFRAME and some representative content in it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is no problem searching through an IFRAME without any additional code: eg. https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/dqBEJd

```
<h1>Searchable IFRAME</h1>

<p>Press CTRL-F to search in the IFRAME.</p>

<iframe width="600" height="600" src="iframetobesearched.htm"></iframe>
```

If you want your own search box (eg. INPUT type="search") in the parent page to *only* search through the IFRAME's content, are you expecting to highlight each of the chosen search words when the user submits the search? Do you want to have a Next / Prev button and to scroll to each instance of the highlighted text?

Comment: Yes, when using the search bar, we would like it to highlight the words. However, we cannot use the shortcut command + F, as it needs to be compatible with mobile devices. We also weren't planning to make a Next / Prev button, but it is definitely an option.